# Not able to execute terminal command(top) in python

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, python-os

I have this command:

```
top -d 1.0 -n 1| grep Mem
```

when i execute it in terminal i get:

```
KiB Mem : 16330216 total,  3902792 free, 10619512 used,  1807912 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8509436 total,  4584448 free,  3924988 used.  4848204 avail Mem
```

I want to save this output in a text file.
I want to keep a track of this every 10 seconds.

Therefore i tried:

```
def repeat():
   print(time.ctime())
   threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
   f= open('ss.txt', 'w')
   top= os.system("sudo top -d 1.0 -n 1| grep Mem")
   s=str(top)
   text = f.write(s)
   print(text)

repeat()
```

But i am only gettin **3** printed.

I want the complete information to be stored in text file.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your output (**3**) is that `os.system()` does not return what is written to `stdout` but the the return value of the executed command (which is normally not printed and therefore not seen by the user).

You, of course, want to get the `stdout` output. The simplest way to get that, is to use `subprocess.run()` rather than `os.system()`. It is generally adviced to use the `subprocess` module, over `os.system()` due to its greater capabilities.

Also, instead of doing a `grep` it is possible to filter the output data in Python itself. This is simpler and removes the need for piping shell commands. Piping shell commands requires `shell=True` as parameter to `subprocess.run()` which may be dangerous, especially if running `sudo`, as it may allow the one executing the program access to all of the system, is not handled carefully. I don't think it is a risk with your current program, but things change and evolve, and all of a sudden it is...

Thus, a solution to your problem would be

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['sudo', 'top', '-d', '1.0', '-n', '1']
p = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

with open('ss.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in p.stdout.split('\n'):
        if 'Mem' in line:
            f.write(line)
```

Unfortunately I am currently not a on Linux machine, so I cannot test the code, which means there may be minor issues, but try it and let me know if it does what you want.

Also note that `subprocess.run()` requires a rather new version of Python (3.5 or newer) otherwise you have to fall back on `p = subprocess.check_output(...)` and `p.communicate()`.

Comment: If you do `print(p.stdout)` directly after `p = subprocess.run(...)` you print nothing?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def repeat():               
   print(time.ctime())  
   threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
   top= os.system("sudo top -d 1.0 -n 1| grep Mem > a.txt")
   with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
       print(str(f.read()))


repeat()
```

Comment: remove sudo and try.

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: @ubuntu 16.04 64 bit