# How to send a stop command from python to terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Python sends:

```
os.system("sudo openvpn openvpn.ovpn")
```

to terminal

how do I tell terminal to listen to my next command
I'm trying to send

```
sys.exit()
```

but it doesn't work

This program is coded with `tkinter` and there is a button to choose the `vpn`,
but i want to make a stop button as well.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to type your sudo password next?

Comment: yea so after i type sudo password, the program will initialize the connection but while it is connecting i cant click anything on my gui, so i thought there should be a way for python to listen to another command while the terminal is still running

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to execute terminal command(top) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766878/not-able-to-execute-terminal-commandtop-in-python)

Comment: thank you! one more question if i use sys.exit() the program will terminate but i want only the terminal to stop how do I send a stop command? right now I'm using subprocess.Popen to send command to terminal

Comment: You might be able to do something with the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Answer (score 2):

`sys.exit` will cause the current process exit. you can try POpen then use one one of

```
Popen.send_signal()
Popen.kill()
Popen.terminate()
```

to cause the subprocess quit. for example:

```
subp = subprocess.Popen("some command" )
subp.send_signal( 9 );
```

Comment: what if right now i have Popen in one def function how do I pass on that value to another function, Popen.kill() requires self.These are under 2 click buttons; one to initiate the connection and the other is to kill the connection

Comment: def clicked():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','openvpn','--config',var.get()])

def clicked2():
    process.kill()

process is in another defined function so I cannot recall it, anyway i can recall that in another function?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
def clicked():
    process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','openvpn','--config',var.get()])

def clicked2():
    process.kill()
```

process is in another defined function so I cannot recall it, anyway i can recall that in another function?